# How do I take a string with a named group and replace only that named capture group with a value in Java 7

Tags: java, regex

Say for example I have the following string with a named capture group:

```
/this/(?<capture1>.*)/a/string/(?<capture2>.*)
```

And I want to replace the capture group with a value like "foo" so that I end up with a string that looks like:

```
/this/foo/a/string/bar
```

Limitations are:

1. Regex must be used as the string is evaluated elsewhere but it doesn't have to be a capture group.
2. I'd rather not have to regex match the regex.
3. **EDIT: There can be many groups in the string.**

Comment: What is your input string? Can you show some code around it?

Comment: The input string is /this/(?<capture1>.*)/a/string/(?<capture2>.*), I dont know what the fully qualified path is and therefore cannot match against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
String string = "/this/(?<capture1>.*)/a/string/(?<capture2>.*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(string);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matches(string);

string.replace(matcher.group("capture1"), "value 1");
string.replace(matcher.group("capture2"), "value 2");
```

Crazy, but works.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the starting and ending index

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {

    startindex= matcher.start();
    stopindex=matcher.end();

// Your code for replacing that index and generating a new string with foo
 // you can use string buffer to delete and insert the characters as you know the indexes   
}

}
```

Full Implementation:

```
public static String getnewString(String text,String reg){

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(text);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {

       int  startindex= matcher.start();
       int stopindex=matcher.end();
       System.out.println(startindex+" "+stopindex);
        result.delete(startindex, stopindex);

        result.insert(startindex, "foo");

    }


    return result.toString();

}
```

Comment: My text is my regular expression I don't have text that matches the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    int lastIndex = s.lastIndexOf("/");

    String newString = s.substring(0, lastIndex+1).concat("newString");
    System.out.println(newString);
```

Get the subString till last '/' and then add new string to the substring like above